# How do I create a Word 2007 form that will tab between text fields, and not within the text field?

Tags: microsoft-word-2007, forms

I am trying to create a protected form in MS Word 2007.  However, once created it won't tab between the text fields, or from a text field to the next field, it only tabs inside of the text fields.  It will tab to the next field for everything else, ie date boxes, list boxes, etc.

I have  tried using the Rich Text control, the Plain Text control, the Text Form field and the Text Box control and it all does the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

What I have found is that you'll need to write macros for each form field:
http://www.word.mvps.org/FAQs/TblsFldsFms/SetTabOrder.htm

I did a different work-around for my own form.  I set it up so that the field I wanted to tab to was below the current, highlighed field.  If you use a table, it'll work.

I created a three-cell table and divided my information accordingly across them.  If you create more than one row, tabbing will go across--and you'll even land on cells where you can't make any entries or changes--so make sure you have a one-row table with columns across.

In each cell, I used a carriage return to add more information/fields.  You can use CTRL+Tab to tab within the cell while you're creating your form for a nice, formatted look.

I used the LEGACY text form field, not the updated Word 2007 one (on the Developer tab in the Controls box, you'll see an icon of a file folder with a couple of tools criss-crossed in front of it).

Once you protect the form, you should be all set.  I imagine you could play around with rows and columns if you need to tab across the form before tabbing down, but you would probably be limited in your options.

Comment: *> Kim won't be able to answer my question* – wrong, look at what I commented on your deleted answer. Your question to Kim has been [appended as a comment](http://superuser.com/questions/158450/how-do-i-create-a-word-2007-form-that-will-tab-between-text-fields-and-not-withi/158595#comment-361763), however is unlikely to ever get a response as this user hasn't visited the site for over a year.

Answer (score 1):

I have MS Word 2010 and this issue seems to be resolved when using plain text boxes (rich text still inserts the tab in the control.)
This may have been resolved in an update to MS Word 2007

Answer (score 1):

I created a form in Word using a table as I designed it. It was pretty awesome. I could change, add and delete cells so that my material would be lined up where I wanted it.

Then, after looking for a long time and resigning myself that my people would have to arrow down between fields, I discovered that tabbing works perfectly if you use regular text rather than rich text.

I had to go in and delete all my old fields and put in new ones just to be absolutely sure that I didn't miss anything and didn't have any residue of the old left in my very long and complicated form.

So, bottom line: Yes, you can tab and it followed the order of my cells perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this solution will work for you, but it's worth a try.  You will need to first protect the document by checking the box for Editing restrictions and pick Filling in Forms from the drop down.

When filling out the form the user will key in their data into the Rich Text box, if they hit tab it will extend the box.  If they hit enter and then tab it will take them to the next field.

I am just a user, not an MVP, or a code writer, but hopefully this will help you out.

Comment: Kim, after the form is protected with the Filling In Forms box checked, the tab key will enter a tab in the text box you're in and the enter key will enter a carriage return. Not sure how you're getting a tab to the next field.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
If KeyCode = 9 Then TextBox2.Activate
End Sub
```

from here: http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=18937

Comment: Geoffrey, I haven't been able to fix coding in a MS word processor since WinWord and I've never been able to figure out VB. Plus, this link brings you to an answer for pre-Word 2007. Word 2007 doesn't give you the tab order option, as far as I've been able to find.

Answer (score 0):

Use a plain text control rather than a rich text control. Rich Text controls will store Tab and Carriage Return (Enter) so pressing either of those keys will not tab to the next field. Alternatively encourage the users to use the mouse instead.